# Backbone class properties? 'this.property' won't work in it's methods?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, web

Help with Backbone needed:

```
var Vehicles = Backbone.Model.extend({}, {
    name: 'Sabre',
    summary: function() {
        console.log(this.name +" is a dog!");
    }
});

Vehicles.summary();
```

This prints out: " is a dog"

Two questions:

1. Why doesn't it print out the name? Why doesn't **this.name** work?
2. On the following line, what is the difference between **firstBlock** and **secondBlock**?

   ```
   Backbone.Model.extend({firstBlock},{SecondBlock});
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html):
`var extend = function(protoProps, staticProps[..]`

Which could be a bit confusing reading the docs:
http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend

> Backbone.Model.extend(properties, [classProperties])

But it means the same :)

The reason the output is 'is a dog' is because `name` and `summary` are static properties of the `Vehicles` model. So `this` won't work in the static `summary` method since it's not an instance you're refering to. You can access those properties without creating an instance.

So this would work:

```
var Vehicles = Backbone.Model.extend({}, {
    foo: 'Sabre',
    staticMethod: function () {
        console.log(Vehicles.foo + " is a dog!");
    }
});

Vehicles.staticMethod();
```

The first argument in the extend are the `protoProps` as seen in the annotated source. So if you want to use those properties, you have to *create a new instance* :

```
var Vehicles = Backbone.Model.extend({
    name: 'Sabre',
    summary: function() {
        console.log(this.name + ' is a dog');
    }
});

var v = new Vehicles();
v.summary();
```

And ofcourse you can combine those two:

```
var Vehicles = Backbone.Model.extend(
    {
        name: 'Sabre',
        summary: function() {
            console.log(Vehicles.bar + ' is a static property');
            console.log(this.name + ' is NOT a static property');
        }
    }, 
    {
        bar: 'foo',
        staticMethod: function() {
            console.log(Vehicles.bar + ' is a static property');
        }
    }
);


var v = new Vehicles();
v.summary();

Vehicles.staticMethod();
```

Comment: The problem is that choosing `bar` as the static property name hides the problem in **(1)**. Try again using `name: 'foo'` instead of `bar: 'foo'` in your  "combined" example and you'll see the original problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at `this` inside your `summary` static method:

```
summary: function() {
    console.log(this);
}
```

you'll see something like this:

```
function (){return r.apply(this,arguments)}
```

so `this` is indeed the constructor function that you'd expect it to be. That means that `this` isn't the problem.

When you say `M = Backbone.Model.extend(...)`, you get a constructor function back in `M`. But, JavaScript functions have non-writeable [`name` properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name):

> **Function.name**
>
> The `function.name` property returns the name of the function.

So the problem is that you're trying to use `name` as a static property but that property name is already taken and you cannot overwrite it.

If you use a different property name:

```
var Vehicles = Backbone.Model.extend({}, {
    pancakes: 'Sabre',
    summary: function() {
        console.log(this.pancakes + " is a dog!");
    }
});
```

then things will behave as expected because functions (usually) don't have non-writeable `pancakes` properties.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/qk78edkp/

As far as your first question goes, it does work but the constructor function that `Backbone.Model.extend` gives you doesn't have a name.

[Pimmol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37608218/479863) covers the second question well enough so I'll leave that alone.

Comment: Wow, nice one. I never could have figured that out

Comment: @Pimmol: This is an insidious problem. Similar to the strange things that can happen if you forget to `var self = this;` and then wonder why `self` is a [window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self).